# How to redraw a previous arrow?

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I'm trying to write a macro `\mappingto` which, basically, called after an arrow has been drawn, should add another one below clarifying what elements are mapped to.

e.g. in an easy situation, I'd like

```
\xymatrix{%
    A \ar[rr]^{f}
      \mappingto{x}{f(x)}
    && B}
```

to expand to

```
\xymatrix{%
    A \ar[rr]^{f}
      \ar@{|->}[]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{x};[rr]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{f(x)}
    && B}
```

The main problem I have is how to get the source and target of the previous arrow? I naively thought that

```
\newcommand{\mappingto}[2]{%
    \POS c="target"
    \POS p="source"
    \ar@{|->}"source"!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#1};"target"!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#2}
}
```

would do the trick, but it obviously doesn't : both items get typeset at the same place, namely below A. I tried all switching of `c` and `p`, including `c=..., c=...` and `p=..., p=...,` in case the `<coord>=<"Id">` does update `c` and `p`, but none did change anything.

I'm pretty convinced now, even though I couldn't find confirmation in the reference manual, that arrows and paths save the `xy` state before being drawn, and restore it afterwards.

So here is my question : is there any way to recover the target of the last drawn arrow?
(Since c is always the source, recovering the source isn't a problem)

I also have considered the following solutions :

- pass the direction again as a parameter : it would work, but I don't really like it,   in the idea of logical coding
- pass the direction as a parameter and make the `\mappingto` macro draw both macros : I'd like to be able to use the `\mappingto` macro with any specific shape, label, position for the "regular" arrow, so it would need a lot of more parameters
- pass the code of the previous arrow as a parameter : Just calling it and saving c and p before or after wouldn't do the trick, because I can already do that.
  I could actually do something with the code of the macro : extract the direction : from `"\ar[rr]^{f}"`, get `"rr"`. I can almost do it using `xstring`, but it seems `xy-pic` can't expand macros inside `[ ]`, so I'm back to step one.

Do you guys see any solution? (preferably in a logical programming mood, aka if I could have a way not forcing me to pass direction or previous arrow to the macro, it would be even nicer ^^)

Minimal example for those who want to experiment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xstring}

 % Clean code version
\newcommand{\mappingtoI}[2]{%
    \POS c="target"
    \POS p="source"
    \ar@{|->}"source"!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#1};"target"!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#2}
}

 % Dirty version
\newcommand{\mappingtoII}[3]{% % First argument is now the first arrow
    \StrBetween{#1}{[}{]}[\direction]
    % Now \direction expands to the direction of the arrow
    #1%     % We draw the first arrow...
    \ar@{|->}[]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#2};[\direction]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#3}
            % ... and then we try to draw the second one.
}

\begin{document}

% % Uncomment this part to see the expected output.    
% Expected output :
% \xymatrix{%
%    A \ar[rr]^{f}
%      \ar@{|->}[]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{x};[rr]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{f(x)}
%    && B
% }

What the basic macro gives :
\xymatrix{%
    A \ar[rr]^{f}
      \mappingtoI{x}{f(x)}
    && B
}

What the "string processing" macro gives : 
 % Won't compile, comment this matrix out if you are trying to get an output!
\xymatrix{%
    A \mappingtoII{\ar[rr]^{f}}
                  {x}{f(x)}
    && B
}        

\end{document}
```

Edit :

It seems I was wrong stating that xy-pic couldn't expand the macros inside direction definition. Now I think xy-pic tries to evaluate `\ar` inside macros arguments. :/

Actually, the following macro

```
\newcommand{\mappingtoTest}[3]{%
    \StrBetween[1]{#1}{[}{]}[\direction]
    \direction
}
```

which should just print the direction of the entered macro, returns an error message

```
!Argument of \next has an extra }.
```

Funny enough, the following macro doesn't return an error :

```
\newcommand{\mappingtoTest}[3]{}
```

Adding `\protect` before `\ar` doesn't help, and I tried to play with `xstring` options, finally getting to this macro, which is the most likely to work at the moment, but still doesn't :

```
\newcommand{\mappingtoTest}[3]{% % First argument is now the first arrow
    \noexpandarg
     \StrBetween{#1}{[}{]}[\direction]
     % Now \direction expands to the direction of the arrow
    \fullexpandarg
    #1%     % We draw the first arrow...
    \ar@{|->}[]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#2};[\direction]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#3}
            % ... and then we try to draw the second one.
}
```

The `noexpandarg` makes a difference though, because

```
\newcommand{\mappingtoTest}[3]{% % First argument is now the first arrow
    \noexpandarg
     \StrBetween{#1}{[}{]}[\direction]}
```

does compile, while the same without `noexpandarg` didn't. If I try to print `\direction`, I get an obscure xy error again, though. :/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

While code snippets are useful for explaining things, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill : Done, and I also added the code of the "dirty" macro.

Comment: Please make sure that your minimal example compiles, otherwise it will be difficult for anybody to find solutions. This is *very* important - see [How to make a “minimum example”](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl). For example, as-is, LaTeX does not "enjoy" your macros `\mappingto1` and `\mappingto2` since they contain numerals. Moreover, use (say) the `article` document class rather than `minimal`, since the latter declares very little in terms of usage for a document to play with.

Comment: @Werner : Done, I just realized you don't necessarily recieve a notification when the main post is edited.

Comment: @T.Verron: Thanks, just received the notification. Why does your code still complain about `Xy-pic error: in entry "1,1": No [rr] (is "1,3") from here.` even if I only leave the `\xymatrix` that you mention one could "Uncomment [..] to see the expected output."?

Comment: @Werner it should be `\ar[r]`and not `\ar[rr]`

Comment: @Werner: Fixed, sorry about that.

I ran some more tests, adding details in the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an expansion problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xstring}

 % Clean code version
\newcommand{\mappingtoI}[2]{%
    \POS c="target"
    \POS p="source"
    \ar@{|->}"source"!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#1};"target"!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#2}
}

 % Dirty version
\newcommand{\mappingtoII}[3]{% % First argument is now the first arrow
    {\noexpandarg\StrBetween{#1}{[}{]}[\direction]
    % Now \direction expands to the direction of the arrow
    #1% We draw the first arrow...
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\ar@{|->}[]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#2};[\direction]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{#3}}\temp
            % ... and then we try to draw the second one.
    }
}

\begin{document}
% Expected output :
 \xymatrix{%
    A \ar[rr]^{f}
      \ar@{|->}[]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{x};[rr]!/:a(-90) 3ex/*{f(x)}
    && B
 }

What the basic macro gives :

\xymatrix{%
    A \ar[rr]^{f}
      \mappingtoI{x}{f(x)}
    && B
}

What the "string processing" macro gives : 


\xymatrix{%
    A \mappingtoII{\ar[rr]^{f}}{x}{f(x)}
    && B
}        

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it indeeds does the trick! I'll mark this as accepted, even though I still hope someone someday will come with a macro satisfying the first, more natural syntax. Thanks again!

Comment: @T.Verron My pleasure.